# Using Regular Expression to Extract Specific Information Through PyPDF2

Tags: python, regex

Any insight on a particular regex to hit the following words within the document?

> ```
> Nama Perseroan :PELABUHAN PATIMBAN INTERNASIONAL
> Nama Singkatan :
> Nomor SP Data
> Perseroan:AHU-AH.01.09-0073201
> Tanggal SP Data
> Perseroan:07 November 2022
> Jenis Perseroan :SWASTA NASIONAL
> NPWP Perseroan :413909557014000DATA PERSEROANRESMI DARI DITJEN AHU
> Jangka Waktu Perseroan :TIDAK TERBATAS
> Status Perseroan :TERTUTUP
> Nomor Telepon :0217917553
> Jenis Transaksi :PERUBAHAN
> ```

The full document text looks something like the listed below.

> ```
> PROFIL PERUSAHAAN PT PELABUHAN PATIMBAN INTERNASIONAL 
> Nama :JONATHAN LOH
> Email :jloh626@gmail.com
> Nomor HP :90018240982109381209821093
> Tanggal Permohonan :16 November 2022 pukul 16:48:33 
> Tanggal Pembayaran:22 November 2022 pukul 08:44:38
> Tujuan Permohonan:lkasjfasdflksdjflkas jflasjflkasjfalsjflaksjDIMOHONKAN OLEH 
> Waktu Unduh PDF :16 Desember 2022 pukul 13:36:19
> Telah diunduh :1 kali INFORMASI BERKAS PDF
> VERIFIKASI BERKAS PDF
> 7. Pemberitahuan Perubahan Data Perseroan Jenis Perubahan :1. Pemberitahuan Perubahan Data Perseroan
> - Direksi dan KomisarisJENIS PERUBAHAN 
> Nama Perseroan :PELABUHAN PATIMBAN INTERNASIONAL
> Nama Singkatan :
> Nomor SP Data
> Perseroan:AHU-AH.01.09-0073201 Tanggal SP Data Perseroan:07 November 2022 
> Jenis Perseroan :SWASTA NASIONAL
> NPWP Perseroan:413909557014000DATA PERSEROANRESMI DARI DITJEN AHU
> Jangka Waktu Perseroan :TIDAK TERBATAS
> Status Perseroan :TERTUTUP
> Nomor Telepon:0217917553
> Jenis Transaksi :PERUBAHAN
> Nama Notaris :DEDY SYAMRI, S.H.
> Kedudukan Notaris :JAKARTA SELATAN 
> Nomor Akta :5
> Tanggal Akta :07 November 2022DATA NOTARIS 
> Alamat :Menara Bank Mega, Lantai 24, Jl.Kapten P Tendean
> Kav. 12-14A
> RT :002
> RW :002
> Kode Pos :12790
> Kelurahan:MAMPANG PRAPATAN
> Kecamatan :MAMPANG PRAPATAN
> Kabupaten :JAKARTA SELATAN
> Provinsi :DKI JAKARTAKEDUDUKAN PERSEROAN
> Data KBLI Tahun :2017
> NoKode
> KBLIJudul KBLI Uraian KBLI
> 152221 AKTIVITAS
> PELAYANAN
> KEPELABUHANAN 
> LAUTKelompok ini mencakup kegiatan usaha pelayanan
> kepelabuhan laut, yang berhubungan dengan angkutan perairan untuk
> penumpang, hewan atau barang, seperti pengoperasian fasilitas terminal
> misalnya pelabuhan dan dermaga, operasi penguncian jalur air dan
> lain-lain, navigasi, pelayaran dan kegiatan berlabuh, jasa penambatan
> dan jasa pemanduanMAKSUD DAN TUJUAN Klasifikasi SahamHarga Per
> LembarJumlah Lembar SahamTotal
> - Rp. 1000 40.000.000 Rp. 40.000.000.000MODAL DASAR Klasifikasi SahamHarga Per LembarJumlah Lembar SahamTotal
> - Rp. 1000 10.000.000 Rp. 10.000.000.000MODAL DITEMPATKANRESMI DARI DITJEN AHU Rp 10.000.000.000 Dalam bentuk uang.MODAL DISETOR Nama
> Jabatan AlamatKlasifikasi 
> SahamJumlah
> Lembar
> SahamTotal
> ALIF SASETYO,
> NIK: 3171060201830005 
> NPWP: 246383541071000
> TTL: Jakarta, 02 Januari 1983DIREKTUR Jalan
> Maluku
> Nomor 19- - -
> ARIEF HERMAWAN,
> NIK: 1271121011700003
> NPWP: 070970173112000
> TTL: Bogor, 10 November 1970KOMISARIS BNR
> Cluster
> Cendana
> C 5/19- - -
> ARLAN SEPTIA ANANDA
> RASAM,
> NIK: 3174051209620003
> NPWP: 080878200013000
> TTL: Jakarta, 12 September
> 1962KOMISARIS Jalan
> Bendi
> IX/125- - -
> CHAIRAL TANJUNG,
> NIK: 3171011605660004
> NPWP: 070141650093000
> TTL: Jakarta, 16 Mei 1966WAKIL
> KOMISARIS 
> UTAMAJalan
> Besuki Nomor 9- - -
> FUAD RIZAL,
> NIK: 3174010201780008
> NPWP: 488337379015000
> TTL: Jakarta, 02 Januari 1978DIREKTUR
> UTAMATebet
> Barat
> Dalam- - -
> Ir. R AGUS HARYOTO
> PURNOMO,
> NIK: 3578032408610001 
> NPWP: 097468813615000
> TTL: SLEMAN, 24 Agustus 1961KOMISARIS
> UTAMARUNGKUT
> ASRI
> TIMUR
> 14/35- - -
> PT CTCORP INFRASTRUKTUR
> INDONESIA,
> Nomor SK :-- Menara
> Bank
> Mega,
> Lantai 24,
> Jalan 
> Kapten
> Pierre
> Tendean
> Kavling
> 12-14A- 3.200.000 Rp.3.200.000.000
> PT INTERPORT PATIMBAN
> AGUNG,
> Nomor SK :-- Graha
> Mitra
> Lantai 7,
> Jalan
> Jenderal
> Gatot
> Subroto
> Kavling 21- 2.900.000 Rp.2.900.000.000
> PT PATIMBAN MAJU BERSAMA,
> Nomor SK :AHU-
> 0061318.AH.01.01.TAHUN 2021 
> Tanggal SK :30 September 2021- Menara
> MTH
> Lantai 11,
> jalan MT
> Haryono,
> kavling 23- 2.900.000 Rp. 2.900.000.000
> PT TERMINAL PETIKEMAS 
> SURABAYA,
> Nomor SK :-- Jalan
> Tanjung
> Mutiara
> Nomor 1- 1.000.000 Rp. 1.000.000.000PENGURUS DAN PEMEGANG SAHAM 
> RESMI DARI DITJEN AHU
> Nama Jabatan AlamatKlasifikasi
> SahamJumlah
> Lembar
> SahamTotal 
> YUKKI NUGRAHAWAN HANAFI,
> NIK: 3174060211670004
> NPWP: 093240992016000
> TTL: Jakarta, 02 November 1967KOMISARIS Jalan
> Cibulan II
> nomor 15- - -
> RESMI DARI DITJEN AHU
> ```

I intend to use PyPDF2 to extract, and is using the re library from python to extract the match text as intended. Below is the code that I tried implementing.

```
import PyPDF2
import re
import pprint
import camelot

pdf_file = 'PDF/File.pdf'

with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as pdf_file:

    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    page_nums = pdf_reader.numPages
    for page_num in range(page_nums):   
        page = pdf_reader.getPage(page_num)
        text = page.extractText()
        string = text
        found = re.search('[A-Z]+[A-Z]+$', string)
    if found:
        print(found.group())
    else:
        print('Not found')
```

Comment: Unclear how your real data looks like (please code format). E.g. if it's a multline input, try something like [`^>? *([^:\n]+)\b *:? *(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/5G6uKY/1) but if it's a single line gets more complicated, maybe [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/puK1BJ/1).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the insight! I just edited and insert the whole text within the document to make it more understandable. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: But how is it formatted? You can add a code block between two `~~~` or intend 4 spaces: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, and thanks for the insight! I just updated so you can see the original formatting that I got on my terminal.

Comment: Sorry to be asking in the comments section, but can you share an insight for regex to capture only the names within the same text file?

Comment: No need to be sorry :) but I'm afraid, I can't help you here any more, it's not clear to me. Maybe an idea to remove the question and ask it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import PyPDF2
import re

class Company: # Filters and extract only company profile within the PDF file

    pdf_file = 'PDF/File.pdf'

    with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as pdf_file:

        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
        page_nums = pdf_reader.numPages
        for page_num in range(page_nums):   
            page = pdf_reader.getPage(page_num)
            text = page.extractText()
            found = re.findall(r'((?:[A-Z][a-z]+\s*)+)\b\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*(?=(?:[A-Z][a-z]+\s*)+:|$)', text)
            if found:
                print(found)
            else:
                print('Not found')
```

Allows us to filter out the specific information indicated on the question column.